# How to expand and fill an array with a single element in typescript?

Tags: typescript

In python, if I want to create an array like `[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]`  I only need to do `[1] * 10`

```
>>> [1] * 10
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

Can I achieve the same in typescript?

Comment: `const array = new Array(10).fill(1);`

Comment: Can you turn it into an answer? I will upvote & accept it.

Comment: @RosdiKasim - Can you turn it into an answer? I will upvote & accept it. --from OP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const array = new Array(10).fill(1);
```

It actually originates from javascript, but of course, works on typescript too.

Answer (score 2):

you can try out

[`Array.from({ length: 10}, () => 1`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) - with this you can provide function that can initialize your array with the function output , currently function returns 1 so it initialize array with 1.

or

[`new Array(10).fill(1);`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill) (Already as given in comment)